# How to build an SQL LIKE clause in Android, where part of the pattern is user-provided

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to filter out query results where a file path contains a user-provided directory name. I'm constructing a clause like the following:

```
path not like '%/UserProvidedDirName/%'
```

I've tried doing this with

```
"path not like '%/" + DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(dirName) + "/%'"
```

and

```
"path not like '%/?/%'" //(passing in the directory as a parameter)
```

but both methods put unwanted single quotes around the directory name:

```
path not like '%/'UserProvidedDirName'/%'
```

I could use `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString()` and then strip the first and last characters from the result, but is there a neater way?

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't `LIKE %"+DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(dirName)+"%` work?

EDIT: just realised what I posted isn't valid SQL, so that's out. I think your best bet is to just trim off the first and last characters using `.substring(1, str.length() - 1)`

Comment: No. That would give me `path not like '%'UserProvidedDirName'%'` which is still a syntax error (and a less specific match too).